# Empty result while creating a csv file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an array with keys and values that I want to email as an attachment in csv form. What I am trying is this:

```
...
$mail->addStringAttachment(create_csv($dataCSV), "test.csv", $encoding = 'base64', $type = "text/csv", $disposition = 'attachment');
...
```

and below that, I declare my `create_csv` function

```
function create_csv(array &$array) {
    if (count($array) == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ob_start();
    $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        fputcsv($df, $key);
        fputcsv($df, $value);
    }
    fclose($df);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This though ends up attaching a file with no contents on my email, even though if I debug `key`, `value` at that point they have the expected values.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check that `create_csv` is actually returning what you expect. I'd also suggest using a `php://temp` stream instead of output so you don't need to use clumsy output buffering, as in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect1-wrappers.php-examples).

Comment: @Synchro thats the thing it does not. It returns nothing. I should try using a temporary file, and I will, but I am stubborn right now, and I want to see what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misuse [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). The function's second argument is a row in the CSV.

If you change your loop to

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($df, [$key, $value]);
}
```

The attached csv will be a list of rows with 2 coma-separated values. e.g. for `$dataCSV = ['one','two','three']` the attachment will be

```
0, one
1, two
2, three
```